# How to add text to image and have the font adjust to the image size.

Tags: c#, .net, text, system.drawing

Suppose i have a phone that i take an image with, i want to take that image and add some text, the text might be long it will contain gps cordinates and date and time of when the image was taken.

In C# .Net by using Graphics, how does one make the font resize according to the image, because when i draw a text, it might fit in the portrait mode image, but in the landscape image it becomes wery small.

Thanks for the answers in advance

Comment: and what have u tried?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986765.aspx I have tried this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function available in Graphics context to measure it. You can refer the following article for more details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986765.aspx